# Is there a photo management software with scripting? (besides Lightroom)

Tags: software, file-management, photo-management

I am looking for photo management software with scripting integrated. I cannot find anything so far besides Adobe Lightroom. Does anyone know if there is an alternative existing?

With the scripting I like to make bulk jobs like:

- Process a bunch of files, for example filtered by etiquette, with an external program.
- Manipulate xmp files (like ACDSee creates).
- Compare a list of files with another list of files, tag the identical files with an etiquette or add them to an album or collection

Comment: Software suggestions for their own sake are off-topic for this site. Can you instead rephrase your question around the specific problem you want to solve (what thing do you want to script, and why) and it may be that the answer is "hey, this software has a scripting feature which matches what you want".

Answer (score 2):

[darktable](http://www.darktable.org) has both a CLI and Lua scripting.